# Modifying a PHP/Mysql timetable

Tags: php, mysql, timetable

I currently have this code:

```
         $rawsql2 = "SELECT 
            *
            FROM 
                _erc_foffices n 
            INNER JOIN 
                _erc_openings o ON n.id = o.branch_id 
            INNER JOIN 
                _erc_openings_times t ON o.id = t.opening_id
            WHERE 
            (
                n.id = %d
            );";

            $sql2 = sprintf($rawsql2, mysql_real_escape_string($id));

            $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

            /*These if & while statements decide whether or not the information should be displayed. If no results are returned from the query above then an alternative message is shown.*/

    if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {

            $count=0;
            $day = 1;
            $timestamp = time();
            $dotw = date('w', $timestamp);
            $dotw = $dotw*2+1;

    echo "<div class='timetable'><p>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    if ($day=='1') { if ($dotw == '1') {echo "<font color='$timetable_colour'>";} echo "<b>Sun - </b>";} 
    else if ($day=='3') { if ($dotw == '3') {echo "<font color='$timetable_colour'>";} echo "<b>Mon - </b>"; } 
    else if ($day=='5') { if ($dotw == '5') {echo "<font color='$timetable_colour'>";} echo "<b>Tue - </b>"; } 
    else if ($day=='7') { if ($dotw == '7') {echo "<font color='$timetable_colour'>";} echo "<b>Wed - </b>"; } 
    else if ($day=='9') { if ($dotw == '9') {echo "<font color='$timetable_colour'>";} echo "<b>Thu - </b>"; } 
    else if ($day=='11') { if ($dotw == '11') {echo "<font color='$timetable_colour'>"; } echo "<b>Fri - </b>"; } 
    else if ($day=='13') { if ($dotw == '13') {echo "<font color='$timetable_colour'>";} echo "<b>Sat - </b>"; } else { echo "";}

        if ($row["open"] == 0 && $row["close"] == 0) {

             if ($day % 2 == 1) {

                    echo "closed<br/></font>";

             }

        }

        else{

               echo "" . substr($row["open"], 0, -3) . "-" . substr($row["close"], 0, -3) . " &nbsp;&nbsp; ";

        if ($count % 2 !=0 ){ echo  "</font><br/>"; } }

               $count++;
               $day++;


                }
            } else {
                    echo "Error";
            }
```

which outputs a timetable like so:

```
Sun - closed
Mon - 08:30-12:30    13:30-16:30   
Tue - 08:30-12:30    13:30-23:59   
Wed - 08:30-12:30    12:30-12:30   
Thu - 08:30-12:30    13:30-16:30   
Fri - 08:30-12:30    13:30-16:30   
Sat - closed
```

The problem I've got now is that some of the embassies have only one opening time a day (e.g. Monday - 0900 - 17:00). With the system I have at the moment, I cannot insert just one time, because it will display the 0900 - 1700 in the monday column, and then the next value along for tuesday, but all in the same row.

Could someone tell me how I can alter my code to recognise that there is only one time for that day and line insert Tuesdays times on the correct line etc? Sorry if I haven't explained it very well, it's quite confusing!

Thanks for any help

Edit:

Mysql table layout:

```
id  opening_id  open    close
    1   3102    00:00:00    00:00:00
    2   3102    00:00:00    00:00:00
    3   3103    08:30:00    12:30:00
    4   3103    13:30:00    16:30:00
    5   3104    08:30:00    12:30:00
    6   3104    13:30:00    23:59:00
    7   3105    08:30:00    12:30:00
    8   3106    09:30:00    12:30:00
    9   3106    13:30:00    16:30:00
    10  3107    08:30:00    12:30:00
    11  3107    13:30:00    16:30:00
    12  3108    00:00:00    00:00:00
    13  3108    00:00:00    00:00:00

_erc_openings table

id  branch_id   dotw
1   1             1
2   1             2
3   1             3
4   1             4
5   1             5
6   1             6
7   1             7

Sun - closed
Mon - 08:30-12:30    13:30-16:30   
Tue - 08:30-12:30    13:30-23:59   
Wed - 08:30-12:30    09:30-12:30   
Thu - 13:30-16:30    08:30-12:30   
Fri - 13:30-16:30    Sat - closed
```

Comment: Please post the table structure you are using, and indent the code correctly. Currently it's unreadable.

Comment: Hi cweiske, is that any better? I'm not very good at sorting out the code neatly but hopefully it's more readable now. I've also added the table layout at the bottom of by post

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything since your while loop simply goes through the rows and shows what's there. If there's only one row of times, it'll only show one set of times.

Comment: Hi Calum, please look at my updated post, I took out a row to show you what I mean. Opening id 3105 now only has 1 entry, so I would want only 1 entry to show next to Wednesday. But instead, it shows Wednesday's time and the first opening for Thursday too, and messes up the layout all down the table

Comment: please do not edit the question away. if you found an answer yourself, post it as an answer.

Comment: Daniel, This question is now useless to anyone else, which goes against the point of Stack Overflow. Please do as @cweiske said: put the question back, and post your answer as an answer.

Comment: sorry cweiske, i'll remember this in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that Daniel H found homself:

I changed this:

```
     if ($row["open"] == 0 && $row["close"] == 0) {
     if ($day % 2 == 1) {
         echo "closed</font>";
     }
}
```

to this:

```
     if ($row["open"] == 0 && $row["close"] == 0) {
     if ($day % 2 == 1) {
         echo "closed</font>";
     }
         if ($day % 2 != 1) {
         echo "<br/></font>";
     }
}
```

and changed the second open/close times to 00:00:00 and it works how I wanted. I think I was over complicating things :/

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP/MySQL here seems fundamentally flawed.  Whatever you're doing with $day and $dotw can't be correct.  Are you doing something to tie the day of the week with the entry in the database?  If so your code isn't displaying it.  Currently your code only looks at the current day of the week when you run the code.  I see the issue you're describing, but in order to resolve that you'll need a way to indicate which times are associated with which days.  Is this what you're trying to accomplish with opening_id?  You never reference this table value in your code

**EDIT**
This still feels incorrectly done since you're just assuming the rows are being passed in the correct order.  The right way to do this would be to add rows to the table that correspond to the day of the week being processed so you can be sure your values are correct, but the quick fix would be to use a saftey bit that you flip on and off, and a variable to track when you're on a new row.  Let me know if this doesn't make sense and I'll try to clarify

```
$saftey = 0;
$lastID = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
if($lastID != $row["opening_id"])
{
    //New Row
    $lastID = $row["opening_id"];
    if($saftey = 0)
    {
        //Everything's fine, do all your processing

        //once that's done
        $saftey = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //There was a first time, but no second time.  Close up here with <br>
    }
}
else
{
    //Not a new row, since this is the 2nd value, process normally and just in case
    $saftey = 0;
}
```

Comment: It is looking at the current day to make it a different colour to the rest of the days displayed. E.g. if the timetable is open now, wednesday will be displayed in green text. It works well if there is 2 entries for each day which was the original spec requested but now I need to alter it so some days can only have 1 entry

Comment: Let me know if that won't work for you, or if something is unclear.  You might have to tweak what I gave you slightly.

Comment: Hi DaOgre, sorry I don't think I mentioned that there is a table that holds the days of the week. I've updated my post now to show this. There is an entry for each day of the week for every embassy, and then the first table I posted takes the id for the current day and displays the times.